# How to show that bound?

Tags: arithmetic

How to show that $\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \dfrac{k+i}{4i}$ is less than or equal to $1/2$ for all
$k \ge 1$ Integer.
I coulden't understand the answer in [How to prove the bound on the probability?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041195/how-to-prove-the-bound-on-the-probability/1041219#1041219)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $u_k=\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \dfrac{k+i}{4i}$. You have $\frac{u_{k+1}}{u_k}= \frac{2k+1}{2k+2}<1$. So $u_k$ is decreasing. The result then follows from $u_1=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: why $\frac{u_{k+1}}{u_k}= \frac{2k+1}{2k+2}$

Comment: Take a pen and compute!

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple mathematical induction.

${\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{k+i}{4i}}$  , $k\geq 1$

**Basis:** $k=1$

$${\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{1} \frac{1+i}{4i}}=\frac{2}{4} \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

Now show that if it holds for any fixed k it also holds for k+1.
Therefore assume $${\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{k+i}{4i}} \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

**Inductive step:** $k \rightarrow k+1$

$$
\begin{gather*}
{\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{k+1+i}{4i}} \\
= {\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{k} \frac{k+i}{4i}} \times \frac{k+1+k}{4k}
\leq \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{k+1+k}{4k} \\
= \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{2+1}{4} \\
= \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{4} \leq \frac{1}{2}
\end{gather*}
$$

q.e.d.

Comment: The first step in the Inductive step is incorrect